# The library hostpolicy.dll was not found

Tags: .net, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I have a simple .NET Core project (console app) that I'm trying to compile and run. `dotnet build` succeeds, but I get the following error when I do `dotnet run`:

```
dotnet run
Project RazorPrecompiler (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in [path].
```

My project.json looks like this:

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "warningsAsErrors": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "Precompiles Razor views.",
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [ ]
    }
  },
  "version": "1.2.0"
}
```

What is `hostpolicy.dll`, and why is it missing?

Comment: I ran into this error when trying to run a custom DotnetCliTool with Visual Studio 2017 RC3 that was missing a runtimeconfig.json. The next VS version will pack it by default. https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5593#issuecomment-277638612

Comment: The same error may be shown, if you  run dotnet MyApp.exe, just run MyApp.exe ["The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required" if run from deploy folder, but emitEntryPoint is true](//stackoverflow.com/a/38333053)

Comment: With the release of asp.net core 2.1 the webjob publish task has a bug/regression that can cause this error if you're targeting the full framework. The fix for this is to pin the sdk to 2.1.200 until it's fixed. You can also delete the `run.cmd` files to quickly get your production jobs running again.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This error message is unhelpful. The **actual** problem is a missing `emitEntryPoint` property:

```
  "buildOptions": {
    ...
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
```

Once this is added, the compiler will let you know about any other problems (like a missing `static void Main()` method). Successfully compiling the project will result in an output that `dotnet run` can execute.

Comment: Since this is still happening in rtm it might be worth noting in the github repo just in case.

Comment: @NickAcosta - I guess these kind of issues are why tooling is preview2 and not rtm (the milestone for the bug is 1.0.0-rtm). Only runtime is rtm.

Comment: How does this work with the new Visual Studio 2017 RC projects, where Microsoft has ditched `project.json` is support of `.csproj` files? As far as I can tell, my project is set up to create an executable.

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja I'd recommend posting a new question.

Comment: I've seen this happen with csproj files too, targeting netcoreapp1.1 in a aspnetcore project.

Comment: Yes, I have a csproj targeting 1.1 and I have this error on first compile. The app always runs if I compile two times in a row.....

Comment: @mrfleck Do you know of a fix so you don't have to run it twice? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Carson - I do not have a fix, but I have logged it as a bug here: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/672  Some folks are having success with the nightly builds, but I am not. The GitHub issue is on their radar and listed as a known issue.

Comment: @mrfleck Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @Carson - Updating to 1.1.1 with the security fix and updating to the latest 2017RC solved this problem for me.

Comment: @mrfleck I'm going to try it out. Thanks for the updates. You're a real champ!

Comment: Thanks @mrfleck  updating from version 1.1 to 1.1.1 fixed my issue

Answer (score 71):

Update for **dotnet core 2.0 and beyond**: the file **appname.runtimeconfig.json** (for both debug and release configuration) is needed in the same path as **appname.dll**.

It contains:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp2.0",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "2.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

then `dotnet.exe exec "path/to/appname.dll" [appargs]` works.

Comment: This answer was partly relevant to me as I'm using dotnet core 2.0 too. Not sure if I did something weird to my workspace, but I also found that I had .dll in both `obj` and `bin` directories. I was in `obj`, and realized that the one in `bin` had this `.runtimeconfig.json` file already. Running that one worked without changes.

Comment: This was the solution for me with dotnet core 3.0 preview 8 also

Comment: How is this file `appname.runtimeconfig.json` generated? If I specify output as exe, it's there. But if it's build as library (and run as `dotnet app.dll`, it's not there.

Answer (score 20):

I had this happen with .NET 6.0 where somehow the `appname.runtimeconfig.dev.json` file was not being generated in the `bin/Debug/net6.0/` directory.

The fix was modifying the `.csproj` file and include this fragment inside the  `<PropertyGroup>` element:

```
<GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>
```

I found this solution while searching with https://www.google.com/search?q=net60+runtimeconfig.dev.json at [Breaking change: runtimeconfig.dev.json file not generated - .NET | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/6.0/runtimeconfigdev-file) with the solution at [MSBuild properties for Microsoft.NET.Sdk - .NET | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props):

> #### GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile
>
> Starting with the .NET 6 SDK, the *[Appname].runtimesettings.dev.json* file is [no longer generated by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/6.0/runtimeconfigdev-file) at compile time. If you still want this file to be generated, set the `GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile` property to `true`.
>
> ```
> <PropertyGroup>
>   <GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>
> </PropertyGroup>
> ```

After applying this to the `.csproj` file and re-building the project, debugging from Visual Studio Code worked fine including stopping at the breakpoints that I had set previously.

Comment: This worked in my case

Comment: If I had asked this question, @Jeroen Wiert Pllumers' answer would have been the accepted answer. (I.e., it just works.)

Answer (score 8):

If I'm not mistaken, one scenario when you can hit the issue is this: You have an integration project that references another application project (not library). In this case, `dependentProject.runtimeconfig.json` won't be copied to your integration project's output folder and you won't be able to run `dependentProject.exe` binary because it will throw `The library hostpolicy.dll was not found.`.

There is a Github [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1675) for this and a [workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ec9d33daf4f1922b2f36f548752ac4539f370c91/eng/testing/runtimeConfiguration.targets#L19).

Edit: Should be [fixed](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/14488) in .NET SDK 5.0.200.

Answer (score 8):

I had similar problem running tests in VS19.

> ========== Starting test run ==========
>
> Testhost process exited with error: A fatal error was encountered. The
> library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not
> found in 'C:\Program Files\dotnet'. Failed to run as a self-contained
> app.

After digging into it I found the source of the problem:

The full path in the `\<my module\>.runtimeconfig.json` in the test binary folder was above 255 characters. Renaming the module, so the file path becomes shorter, resolved the problem.

Comment: Exactly our case on the AzureDevops ms hosted pipeline on .NET6. That was pretty untrackable since we haven't been able to look at what's inside ms hosted deployed VM.
I have tried to recreate the whole project from the scratch and then get the warning about the path. That was the only hint. Upvote for you @SergeyL.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting similar error while running Unit tests using **VSTest@2** task in Azure Devops.
In my case, the problem was with my **testAssemblyVer2** value. I was giving wrong pattern for test dlls.

Below one worked for me.(if you are getting this error with VSTest)

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Running UnitTests'
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\SrcFolder\BBBB.UnitTests\**\bin\**\*.BBBB.UnitTests.dll
      $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\SrcFolder\AAAAa.UnitTests\**\bin\**\*.AAAA.UnitTests.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    platform: x64
    configuration: Debug
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
```

So try to give correct pattern value for testAssemblyVer2 input. Make sure its filtering only the required dlls.

Comment: I used this for my MSTest projects in a solution build where my projects are named 'xxxxUnitTests':
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\*UnitTests\**\bin\**\*UnitTests.dll

Answer (score 3):

This occurred when a Visual Studio 2019 preview upgrade .Net Core to the latest preview (specifically .Net Core 3.1.100-preview2-014569).

Reinstalling/repairing .Net Core 3.0.100 solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why but I ran in to the problem when executing the .exe file in my \bin folder while the .exe in my \obj folder works fine.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25453092)

Comment: Thank you. I'm just sharing how I fixed the same error in my build. :)

Answer (score 3):

I am having this problem in Dotnet Core 3.1 Console application.

If you are publishing your application, make sure that your **target runtime** set to the specific runtime that you had installed in your target machine.

If you set to **portable** it will pick whatever runtime that it feels comfortable (which you might not have it installed)

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was with the version mismatch. I had a different ".Net core SDK" version installed and a different version was specified in .json file.

Once I modified the version in my .json file the application started working fine.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was because I was publishing a self-contained application for the wrong target. My intent was to run on alpine linux, but I was building for `libc` when I should have been building for `musl`.

The failing package was built using:

```
dotnet publish --self-contained true --runtime linux-x64 --framework netcoreapp2.1 --output /app
```

Changing the RID:

```
dotnet publish --self-contained true --runtime linux-musl-x64 --framework netcoreapp2.1 --output /app
```

produced a functional package. Notice the RID changed from `linux-x64` to `linux-musl-x64`. If I had read the [.NET Core RID Catalog page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#linux-rids) this could have been avoided.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when moving the folder

C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.32
to
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.32

In my case I had an API that runs on ISS and gets hosted there.
I found out you can also download a runtime version with a windows hosting bundle.
this bundle gets installed in the right folder and has the hostpolicy.dll file included.

This did it for me.

Comment: This resolved my issue. Here is the link for the hosting bundle I had to use for 3.1: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-3.1.32-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you didn't want to do a "Console .Net Core" project but a "Console .Net Framework" project. It solves the problem, for me...

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I have **2 .NET Core App projects** and one is **dependent on the other**.
*(so I can then execute that application from that other application)*
But .NET Core applications *(with default config)* **need <assembly name>.runtimeconfig.json file** *(to get some launch config)* which isn't copied by default.

---

The only solution that worked for me was adding to Project Properties > Build Events *(of the dependent project)* this command:

```
COPY "$(SolutionDir)<dependency name>\$(OutDir)<dependency assymbly name>.runtimeconfig.json" "$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)\$(OutDir)" /Y
```

But you can also copy the <dependency assembly name>.runtimeconfig.json file by hand to the dependent project.

---

*Note that there should be a better more generic way to do this for every .NET Core App Project automatically.*

Answer (score 1):

This error is quite generic. So the real problem can be anything.

In my case (if helps anyone with same issue), I created a Class Library project instead of a Console Application project.

A Class Library DLL can't be runned with MSBuild, even if it has a Main method.
Only Console Application DDL can be runned as `dotnet <appname>.dll`

Answer (score 1):

Add the OutputType on the PropertyGroup and issue is solved

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

more about this MSBuild can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score 0):

For me with ASP.NET Core 2.0 on Azure, it was the appname.deps.json that did the trick. You need to copy it from your build directory to Azure.

Comment: So what did you do to this file, please

Comment: @YoussefSherif You need to copy it from your build directory to Azure. I thought it could be omitted but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with a .NET Core 3.0 WPF app, but I found that my app wouldn't run in Visual Studio 2019 either.

I discovered on the project properties page (right-click on project > Properties) that the Target framework was set to .NET Core 3.0.

I'd recently updated VS 2019 which had also installed .NET Core 3.1, so I switched to that in the dropdown, and it worked again.

(I also had to update my shortcut to point to the netcoreapp3.1 folder instead of the previous netcoreapp3.0 folder.)

Answer (score 0):

Promoting voltrevo's comment as an answer as I believe this should be the most common case of the problem. When you build your solution, sometimes you might get 2 directories with outputs bin and obj. 'Bin' directory has everything that is needed to run dotnet.exe command. Just run from the bin directory and things should be good. :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error occurred during the SonarQube coverage scan due to one of the projects had a project reference to a MSTest project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and it took me couple of days to figure out the solution.

1. Go to Visual Studio Installer.
2. Click on 'More' option of the Visual Studio.
3. Select 'Repair'.

It'll take some time for the download and installation.
Once it's completed restart the machine and try again.
This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.  We installed new frameworks, but never restarted IIS.  Restarting IIS via this command fixed it:
`iisreset /restart`

Answer (score 0):

I started receiving this error using .NET Maui .net6 after modifying the launchSettings.json.  Apparently the error was being thrown due to invalid configuration option.  I renamed the file and allowed it to regenerate and then the error was resolved.  When comparing the two I am assuming that one of the values I changed was not compatible with the project.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer which helped me.  Are you perhaps running from the `obj` directory by mistake?  You should use the `bin` directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be related when DevOps tries to run tests over `Microsoft` or other third party DLL instead of just the unit tests of your project.

The default "file matching patterns" lists those dependencies and try to run tests over it, which will fail. The first file for me was the real Test.DLL I need, and the tests passed as expected, the the other binaries fail.

If this is happening, you will see the files on the DevOps pipeline, and also a large count of files will be display, like this:

```
vstest.console.exe "D:\a\1\s\YourProject.Test\bin\Release\net8.0\YourProject.Test.dll"
"D:\a\1\s\YourProject.Test\bin\Release\net8.0\Microsoft.TestPlatform.AdapterUtilities.dll"
"D:\a\1\s\YourProject.Test\bin\Release\net8.0\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.dll"
"D:\a\1\s\YourProject.Test\bin\Release\net8.0\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.dll"   "D:\a\1\s\YourProject.Test\bin\Release\net8.0\Microsoft.Testing.Extensions.Telemetry.dll"

(...)
A total of 58 test files matched the specified pattern.
```

**file-matching-patterns**:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops

So you can try to modify your filter to exclude (!) Microsoft or other tests from the pipeline task, for example, this pattern below works for me:

**Pattern suggestion:**

```
**\release\**\*test*.dll
!**\testhost.dll
!**\*Microsoft.VisualStudio.Test*
!**\**\*Microsoft.VisualStudio.Test*
!**\*Microsoft.Test*
!**\**\*Microsoft.Test*
!**\obj\**
```