# "The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required" if run from deploy folder, but emitEntryPoint is true

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, project.json, dotnet-cli

I created a Web API project using the default ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) template and then published to local folder using VS.

Now if I call `dotnet application.exe` in the console, I receive the following error:

> A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found

I have found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38085431/2833802) and this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2859) on github, that the actual problem is a missing emitEntryPoint property. All is fine, except that my project.json already has `"emitEntryPoint": true`

What else can cause this error?

Comment: Does your application work in Visual Studio debug mode, before publishing?

Comment: yes, and it works if use 'dotnet run' from project folder

Comment: What happens if you run the published `.exe`, without using `dotnet`?

Comment: hm, don't know why I haven't check this, cause it works fine. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Posted it as an answer in case anyone else runs into this! :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Once you publish the application and have a .exe file, you don't need to use `dotnet` anymore. The application is compiled!

Just run application.exe by double-clicking it, or launching it from the console.

Comment: I can't get VS to generate exe even after I publish. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: @Mayank Sounds like your csproj file may not be correct. I'd recommend posting a new question with the contents of your csproj file.

Comment: @Mayank, can you verify if the .Net core SDK version installed is same as the one specified in global.json file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install the correct version of ASP Net Core in the server.

Here is the download link:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core

Answer (score -2):

We ran in the same problem building our app in CI. Apparantly a reference towards another unittest project slipped in. This Created the error at hand.