# deploying webjobs through CI-CD pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have a continuous webJob and am running it through CI-CD pipeline. After successful release webjob is showing as restart pending. Getting an error in the logs

> D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\MiddleCompassServer\rrwnz5aj.4el>dotnet
>   MiddleCompassServer.exe
>
> A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required
>   to execute the application was not found in
>   'D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\MiddleCompassServer\rrwnz5aj.4el\'.
>
> Failed to run as a self-contained app. If this should be a
>   framework-dependent app, add the
>   D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\MiddleCompassServer\rrwnz5aj.4el\MiddleCompassServer.runtimeconfig.json
>   file specifying the appropriate framework.

Comment: If i run the same through Visual Studio the status of Web Job is Running.. This error is happening only through Pipeline

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085430/the-library-hostpolicy-dll-was-not-found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was chance that the dotnet core version specified in .json file mismatch with the version installed. You can try the solutions given in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085430/the-library-hostpolicy-dll-was-not-found) mentioned by TrevorBrooks.

If above thread didnot workout for you.Try run .exe directly from console (`./MiddleCompassServer.exe` ) without using dotnet. as pointed out in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332512/the-library-hostpolicy-dll-required-if-run-from-deploy-folder-but-emitentry).

You can also try adding the `runtimes` setting in project.json and modify the `RuntimeIdentifiers` in .csproj file as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42396782/error-loading-hostpolicy-dll-while-deploying-net-core-console-app-to-azure-webj/42402180) pointed out.