# How to run .net console application (built on windows) on Linux using .net core

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core

I'm trying to run a .net console application on Linux using .net core, 
I built this application on windows. these are the steps I took:

1. Build the project in VS2015 .net 4.6.1 (Windows).
2. Copy the output directory to Linux machine.
3. Run the command `dotnet QL3.exe`

I get the following error message:

**A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/home/ubuntu/QL3'.**

*comment: when I take those same step but use mono the application runs.*

Suggestions?

Comment: @patrick-hofman I think the difference is that I'm not trying to build it in Linux but only run it. is it not allowed? must I build the project in Linux in order for it to work?

Comment: The other posts also says: "I get the following error when I do dotnet run", so the problem is in the running too, not the compiling.

Comment: That is correct but I don't have this Project.json file, I just copied the output directory to the Linux machine and ran the exe (using dotnet command). I understand that I probably did something wrong I'm just trying to understand what.

Comment: You need the project file for compiling, which works in the duplicate. Ignore that.

Comment: so if I ignore that all that left is update to 1.1.1, is that it?

Comment: Did you read the other answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/38085431/993547 If that doesn't help, update your question and explain all steps you have done.

Comment: I'm sorry but there is only one answer in the link you sent I read it (something to do with adding a property to the project.json which you said is not relevant to my problem). I updated my question if you still think its a duplicate I'm not saying that you're wrong but that doesn't mean that i don't still need help.