# Hostpolicy.dll not found error when running .NET Core from Python

Tags: python, .net-core, pipe

i am trying to run a `Net Core Application` from python and i am getting this error message:

```
 error:"A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'D:\\BenchmarkingApp\\BenchmarkingApp\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.1\\'.\r\nFailed to run as a self-contained app. If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the D:\\BenchmarkingApp\\BenchmarkingApp\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.1\\BenchmarkingApp.runtimeconfig.json file specifying the appropriate framework.\r\n"
```

Why do i get this error ?

**Python code**

```
import subprocess
csServerPath = "D:\\BenchmarkBuild\server\Server.dll"

def main():
    command = "dotnet D:\\BenchmarkingApp\\BenchmarkingApp\\bin\Debug\\netcoreapp2.1\\BenchmarkingApp.dll 1 2 3"
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (output, err) = process.communicate()
    print("output:"+str(output))
    print("error:"+str(err))

main()
```

**P.S** If you point me towards this link : [The library hostpolicy.dll was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085430/the-library-hostpolicy-dll-was-not-found) as duplicate, i have  the `appname.runtimeconfig.json` in the same path with the `appname.dll`

Comment: Is this problem only while invoking from Python? Does `dotnet D:\\BenchmarkingApp\\BenchmarkingApp\\bin\Debug\\netcoreapp2.1\\BenchmarkingApp.dll 1 2 3` from command line?

Comment: It did not work in the terminal either.I have solved the `hostpolicy`  problem by adding the `appname.runtimeconfig.json`.But now i get `Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (BenchmarkingApp.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Newtonsoft.Json', version: '11.0.2'
    path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
`