# An error occurred while loading required library hostpolicy.dll

Tags: c#, sql, database, macos, visual-studio

This error comes up when trying to perform initial add-migration on a sql database in Visual Studio 2022. However when I check the Dll path it is there. My computer is a Macbook and I do Windows virtualization to run VS 2022 and the operating system is Arm 64 bit.

`Failed to load the dll from [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.16\hostpolicy.dll], HRESULT: 0x800700C1 An error occurred while loading required library hostpolicy.dll from [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.16]`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be duplicate of ["The library hostpolicy.dll was not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085430/the-library-hostpolicy-dll-was-not-found).

Based on a more recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62790238/4513334)...this issue may have been resolved in `5.0.2`.  You could consider updating your SDK version.

Comment: I installed .NET 5.0.2 as you said but Visual Studio continues to recognize the previous version and displays the same message.

Comment: This link might help https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2533623/microsoft-security-advisory-insecure-library-loading-could-allow-remot